# Python: typeerror: unorderable types

Tags: python

I am trying to run this program on my 3.5 python environment but it would give me this error:
"typeerror: unorderable types",  in line 33:

```
heappush(tree, (total_prob, x, y))
```

Here is the program

```
# Native binary tree implementation
from heapq import heapify, heappop, heappush

def printCodes(t, code_str = ''):
    '''
    Accept the root node of a 'heapq' tree and print the Huffman codes.
    This function uses recursion to build the codes strings.
    '''
    if len(t) < 3:
        print('%s: %s' % (t[1], code_str))
    else:
        printCodes(t[1], code_str + '0')
        printCodes(t[2], code_str + '1')

# Initialize the input (data taken from 3.20)
tree = [
    [0.07, 'a'],
    [0.09, 'b'],
    [0.12, 'c'],
    [0.22, 'd'],
    [0.23, 'e']
]

# Convert the input into a binary tree
heapify(tree)

# Sort the tree into a valid Huffman tree.
# To do this, pop two nodes, then push them back into the tree under a
# node with the combined total probability
while len(tree) > 1:
    x = heappop(tree)
    y = heappop(tree)
    total_prob = x[0] + y[0]
    heappush(tree, (total_prob, x, y))

# Output
printCodes(tree[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's from comparing lists with tuples.  Creating your tree structure like this instead should solve it:

```
tree = [
    (0.07, 'a'),
    (0.09, 'b'),
    (0.12, 'c'),
    (0.22, 'd'),
    (0.23, 'e'),
]
```